# valgrind on child process is not working properly. all the processes are down after 10 mins

Tags: fork, valgrind

I ran below command

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --verbose --trace-children=yes --trace-children-skip=.*/ton,.*/zip,.*/cntr,.*/sif,.*/cms,.*/man,.*/cer,.*/ltask,.*/ftask,.*/ice --log-file=/home/temp/valgrind.log ./bin/acloader
```

when I removed option `-trace-children=yes`, everything is working fine. but with this option whole processes went down in 10 mins. what could be the cause for it and solution ? I need to find the leak in one of the child process.

Comment: What is "processes are down"?

Comment: It seems all the processes are self killed.